# How to run backstop.js with Firefox on Ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, regression, backstop.js

How to run backstop.js with Firefox because in the official documentation for property `engine` I can set only chromy or puppeteer engine instance in the config file

```js
module.exports = options => ({
    id: "zing-web",
    viewports: [
        {
            label: "laptop",
            width: 1366,
            height: 920
        }
    ],
    onBeforeScript: "puppet/onBefore.js",
    onReadyScript: "puppet/onReady.js",
    scenarios: options.scenarios,
    paths: options.paths,
    engine: "puppeteer",
    engineOptions: {
        args: ["--no-sandbox"]
    },
    report: ["CI"],
    asyncCompareLimit: options.asyncScreens || 10, // Capturing screens in parallel
    asyncCaptureLimit: options.asyncScreens || 50, // Comparing screens in parallel
    debug: options.debug,
    debugWindow: options.debug
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today there is no official support for Firefox browsers with Backstopjs. However you can use it with [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) engine that supports Chromium, Firefox and Webkit (Safari for MacOS).